# How to annotate the area of a polyline in autocad command / macro

Tags: autocad

Does anyone know of macro or custom command I can make to quickly annotate the area of a polyline in autocad?

I'm doing a project where I need to measure the lot and house size of several city blocks.  I've got a drawing going but I don't want to measure and write out the area of each site, that will take to long.  I've seen custom commands in the past that quickly do this kind of thing but I don't know how to make my own.

And I'm desperately avoiding doing it by hand one at a time as most likely I will need to make adjustments to my design later on.

Comment: Have you considered writing a VBA macro? It could loop all of the chosen polyline data, getting the area values and then creating the MXTEXT/TEXT objects at the approximate center of the shapes.

Answer (score 3):

The best method I can think of is to utilize the MTEXT command and use a FIELD to link the Area of the Polyline to the MTEXT box.

> Type FIELD at the command line, choose Object, select your Polyline and you will see the Area property.

Here is a link on the CADTutor site that covers it a bit more in depth along with a link to a forum post that has this automated via a Lisp routine.

http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/archive/index.php/t-46628.html